# Prevent caching on Custom Display Name Attributes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a Custom Display Name attribute that translates the field names based on the user's language preference.  Unfortunately what happens is that the first user's language preference is cached for every subsequent request regardless of the subsequent user's language preference.  The result is that the page content, header, and menu items display in the proper language, but only the labeled fields display with the incorrect language.

Here is part of the View Model I'm using:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [CustomEmailAddress]
    [CustomDisplayName("lbl_email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }    
    [CustomRequired]
    [CustomDisplayName("lbl_fn")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    
    ...
}
```

Here is the Custom Display Name attribute:

```
public class CustomDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        public CustomDisplayNameAttribute(string value = "")
            : base(GetMessageFromResource(value))
        {
        }

        private static string GetMessageFromResource(string value)
        {
            string CurrentUser;
            try
            {
                CurrentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            catch
            {
                CurrentUser = "";
            }
            string lang = ModelInit.repo.LangCode(CurrentUser);
            string ItemLegend = ModelInit.repo.TranslateItem(value, lang);
            return ItemLegend;
        }
    }
```

While debugging the problem, I found that MVC does NOT bother to hit the "CustomDisplayNameAttribute" class on subsequent requests even after the user logs off and a new user logs on.  So I also tried decorating the Custom Display Attribute with:

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

but it didn't work either.  If this behavior can't be changed (because it's built-in to the framework) then is there a way to clear the cache from the Custom Display Name attribute when the user logs off?  (Actually, this would be my preferred solution!) Right now, the only way to clear it is by stopping and restarting the program.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

OutputCacheAttribute is used to cache the output of the entire controller method, but has nothing to do with caching of the model attributes.  Since attributes are simply static metadata, MVC needs to use reflection to retrieve it, and the effect of this relatively slow operation is minimized by caching the result.

Unfortunately there is no way to clear this cache, likely because doing so in a multi-threaded, safe manner would require locking that would hinder performance.

Note that there are multiple caches in use throughout MVC, including **model** metadata, **view** location, and (optional) **controller** output.  Each uses a separate implementation and cache key strategy, which I discovered when trying to create multi-tenancy on top of MVC.  Things have gotten a little better (easier) with MVC 6.